# Multivariable Taylor expansion using tensor notation?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, notation, vector-analysis

A [course note](https://erdogdu.github.io/csc2532/notes/22/lec03.pdf) I am reading uses the following notation for the Taylor expansion of a functtion $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$:
$$
f(x) = f(x_0) + \nabla f(x_0)[x-x_0] + \dfrac{1}{2} \nabla^2f(x_0)[x-x_0, x-x_0] + \dfrac{1}{6} \nabla^3 f(x_0)[x-x_0, x-x_0, x-x_0]
$$
where $\nabla f(x_0) \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $\nabla^2 f(x_0) \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$, and $\nabla^3 f(x_0) \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d \times d}$.

Particularly, the lecturer defines the tensor notations by

[image]

I do not understand how $\nabla^3$ and $A[u,u,u]$ are defined. Where can I find its formal treatment?

Comment: This should become clear when you have studied the [multi index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Generalizations_of_Taylor.27s_theorem) of that formula.

Comment: $$\nabla^{3}f(x)(u, v, w) = \sum_{i,  j, k = 1}^{n}f_{x_i x_j x_k}u_i v_j w_k$$ and higher powers are defined similarly.